# UISlider with ProgressView combined

Tags: objective-c, ios4, streaming, uislider, uiprogressview

Is there an apple-house-made way to get a UISlider with a ProgressView. This is used by many streaming applications e.g. native quicktimeplayer or youtube.
(Just to be sure: i'm only in the visualization interested)

[image: Slider with loader]

cheers Simon

Comment: Use MPVolumeView included in the SDK http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's a simple version of what you're describing.

[image]

It is "simple" in the sense that I didn't bother trying to add the shading and other subtleties. But it's easy to construct and you can tweak it to draw in a more subtle way if you like. For example, you could make your own image and use it as the slider's thumb.

This is actually a UISlider subclass lying on top of a UIView subclass (MyTherm) that draws the thermometer, plus two UILabels that draw the numbers.

The UISlider subclass eliminates the built-in track, so that the thermometer behind it shows through. But the UISlider's thumb (knob) is still draggable in the normal way, and you can set it to a custom image, get the Value Changed event when the user drags it, and so on. Here is the code for the UISlider subclass that eliminates its own track:

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect result = [super trackRectForBounds:bounds];
    result.size.height = 0;
    return result;
}
```

The thermometer is an instance of a custom UIView subclass, MyTherm. I instantiated it in the nib and unchecked its Opaque and gave it a background color of Clear Color. It has a `value` property so it knows how much to fill the thermometer. Here's its `drawRect:` code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGFloat ins = 2.0;
    CGRect r = CGRectInset(self.bounds, ins, ins);
    CGFloat radius = r.size.height / 2.0;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(r) - radius, ins);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, radius+ins, radius+ins, radius, -M_PI/2.0, M_PI/2.0, true);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(r) - radius, radius+ins, radius, M_PI/2.0, -M_PI/2.0, true);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CGContextAddPath(c, path);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
    CGContextAddPath(c, path);
    CGContextClip(c);
    CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(r.origin.x, r.origin.y, r.size.width * self.value, r.size.height));
}
```

To change the thermometer value, change the MyTherm instance's `value` to a number between 0 and 1, and tell it to redraw itself with `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: I have got invalid context error in Xcode 5.1 because of this line result.size.height = 0

Comment: @Rams how to avoid it?

Comment: I was also getting four graphics context-related errors due to overriding `trackRectForBounds:` and setting the height to 0. To resolve this, I replaced the min and max track images with new (transparent) images in the init method. I.e., `[self setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` and `[self setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`.

Comment: @orkenstein, I have fixed it by 0.01(nonzero).

Answer (score 20):

This is doable using the standard controls.

In Interface Builder place your `UISlider` immediately on top of your `UIProgressView` and make them the same size.

On a `UISlider` the background horizontal line is called the track, the trick is to make it invisible. We do this with a transparent PNG and the `UISlider` methods `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:` and `setMaximumTrackImage:forState:`.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller add:

```
[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where `self.slider` refers to your `UISlider`.

I've tested the code in Xcode, and this will give you a slider with an independent progress bar.

Comment: I went with this solution, but rather than bundling a transparent png you can create a transparent 1 pixel UIImage at runtime with..

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((CGSize){ 1, 1 }, NO, 0.0f);
UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: ok. But the passed video/audio duration doesn't displayed, how to fix it?

Comment: @SamDoshi I only setMaximumTrackImage, but it affects the minimumTrackImage also, ?

Answer (score 5):

Solution that suits my design:

```
class SliderBuffering:UISlider {
    let bufferProgress =  UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Default)

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bufferProgress.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bufferProgress.userInteractionEnabled = false
        bufferProgress.progress = 0.0
        bufferProgress.progressTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        bufferProgress.trackTintColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        self.addSubview(bufferProgress)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a UISlider:

```
// 1
// Make the slider as a public propriety so you can access it
playerSlider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
[playerSlider setContinuous:YES];
[playerSlider setHighlighted:YES];
// remove the slider filling default blue color
[playerSlider setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[playerSlider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
// Chose your frame
playerSlider.frame = CGRectMake(--- , -- , yourSliderWith , ----);

// 2
// create a UIView that u can access and make it the shadow of your slider 
shadowSlider = [[UIView alloc] init];
shadowSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
shadowSlider.frame = CGRectMake(playerSlider.frame.origin.x , playerSlider.frame.origin.y , playerSlider.frame.size.width , playerSlider.frame.origin.size.height);
shadowSlider.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
shadowSlider.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[playerSlider addSubview:shadowSlider];
[playerSlider sendSubviewToBack:shadowSlider];


// 3
// Add a timer Update your slider and shadow slider programatically 
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)updateSlider {

    // Update the slider about the music time
    playerSlider.value = audioPlayer.currentTime; // based on ur case 
    playerSlider.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;

    float smartWidth = 0.0;
    smartWidth = (yourSliderFullWidth * audioPlayer.duration ) / 100;
    shadowSlider.frame = CGRectMake( shadowSlider.frame.origin.x , shadowSlider.frame.origin.y , smartWidth , shadowSlider.frame.size.height);

   }
```

Enjoy! P.S. I might have some typos.

Answer (score 3):

**Idea 1:**
You could easily use the UISlider as a progress view by subclassing it. It responds to methods such as 'setValue:animated:' with which you can set the value (i.e: progress) of the view.

Your only 'restriction' creating what you see in your example is the buffer bar, which you could create by 'creatively' skinning the UISlider (because you can add custom skins to it), and perhaps set that skin programmatically.

**Idea 2:**
Another (easier) option is to subclass UIProgressView, and create a UISlider inside that subclass. You can skin the UISlider to have a see-through skin (no bar, just the knob visible) and lay it over the UIProgressView.

You can use the UIProgressView for the pre-loading (buffering) and the UISlider for movie control / progress indication.

Seems fairly easy :-)

**Edit:** to actually answer your question, there is no in-house way, but it would be easy to accomplish with the tools given.

Comment: sorry but i have no idea how to subclassing a UIProgressView into a UISlider. Although you helped me further and answered my question I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some trick like this, it's more easy and understanding. Just insert the code bellow in your UISlider subclass.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (_availableDurationImageView == nil) {
        // step 1 
        // get max length that our "availableDurationImageView" will show
        UIView *maxTrackView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:self.subviews.count - 3];
        UIImageView *maxTrackImageView = [maxTrackView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        _maxLength = maxTrackImageView.width;

        // step 2
        // get the right frame where our "availableDurationImageView" will place in       superView
        UIView *minTrackView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:self.subviews.count - 2];
        _availableDurationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage     imageNamed:@"MediaSlider.bundle/4_jindu_huancun.png"]     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 0, 2)]];
        _availableDurationImageView.opaque = NO;
        _availableDurationImageView.frame = minTrackView.frame;

        [self insertSubview:_availableDurationImageView belowSubview:minTrackView];
    }
}


- (void)setAvailableValue:(NSTimeInterval)availableValue
{
    if (availableValue >=0 && availableValue <= 1) {
        // use "maxLength" and percentage to set our "availableDurationImageView" 's length
        _availableDurationImageView.width = _maxLength * availableValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on matt's solution, note that as of iOS 7.0, implementing trackRectForBounds: is rendered impossible. Here is my solution to this problem :

In your UISlider subclass, do this :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UIImage* clearColorImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:clearColorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:clearColorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

with imageWithColor as this function :

```
+ (UIImage*) imageWithColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    return [UIImage imageWithColor:color andSize:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
}
```

That will properly take care of this annoying trackRectangle.

I spent too much time looking for a solution to this problem, here's hoping that'll save some time to another poor soul ;).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution in Objective C. https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/BufferSlider](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/BufferSlider)

The idea is to create a UIProgressview as a property in the UISlider subclass and add the required constraints programatically.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> //.h file

@interface BufferSlider : UISlider
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIProgressView *bufferProgress;
@end

#import "BufferSlider.h" //.m file

@implementation BufferSlider


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setup {
    self.bufferProgress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.value = 0.2;
    self.bufferProgress.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.bufferProgress.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.bufferProgress.progress = 0.7;
    self.bufferProgress.progressTintColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    self.bufferProgress.trackTintColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:2];
    [self addSubview:self.bufferProgress];
    [self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redThumb"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.bufferProgress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bufferProgress attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bufferProgress attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0.75];  // edit the constant value based on the thumb image
    NSLayoutConstraint *right = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bufferProgress attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0];

    [self addConstraints:@[left,right,centerY]];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.bufferProgress];
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Swift5**

First, add tap gesture to slider:

```
let tap_gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.sliderTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
self.slider.addGestureRecognizer(tap_gesture)
```

Then, implement this function:

```
@objc func sliderTapped(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let locationOnSlider = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.slider)
    let maxWidth = self.slider.frame.size.width
    let touchLocationRatio = locationOnSlider.x * CGFloat(self.slider.maximumValue) / CGFloat(maxWidth)
    self.slider.value = Float(touchLocationRatio)
    
    print("New value: ", round(self.slider.value))
   
}
```