# What is this iOS UI Element called, and how do I make one?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uislider, uiprogressview

In the picture below, I have drawn on the element I am trying to figure out how to make. It is a cross between a UISlider and a UIProgressview. It has the style and look of a UIProgressview, but has a ...slider like a UISlider. How would I make one of these regularly? Nearly every music player has them... :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISlider with ProgressView combined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495433/uislider-with-progressview-combined)

Comment: Okay, try to add another snapshot without the nudie pic in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the volume slider or the track progress?

If it is the volume slider, its just the normal UISlider.

And if you're talking about the track progress, then it is also a UISlider. The difference is that every time  a second passes in the track, it updates the position of the slider relative to the position in the track. Then when the user slides the slider it updates the position of the track relative to the position of the slider

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm asking for the styling, as in it has the white light on top and the different scrubber handle, as the UISlider is much more bland. (Just a blue gradient and a circle, this one is blue with a shine and a shine'd scrubber)

Comment: The styling for the volume slider comes from the `MPVolumeView` class. If you want to use a slider like that for custom functionality, you'll likely have to provide custom images with the appearance you're looking for for the `currentMinimumTrackImage`, `currentMaximumTrackImage`, and `currentThumbImage` properties in your `UISlider`. Or you could subclass `UISlider` entirely and customize the look further.