# Objective c - Display buffering progress when playing audio from remote server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play audio from remote server.

I want to display a progress bar showing the buffering progress and the "time played" progress, like the `MPMoviePlayerController` does when you play a movie.

Does the `AVPlayer` has any UI component that display this info? If not, how can I get this info (buffering state)?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Does the AVPlayer has any UI component that display this info?

No, there's no UI component for AVPlayer.

### If not, how can I get this info (buffering state)?

You should observer `AVPlayerItem.loadedTimeRanges`

```
[yourPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

then using KVO to watch

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == player.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"loadedTimeRanges"]){
        NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray*)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
            CMTimeRange timerange=[[timeRanges objectAtIndex:0]CMTimeRangeValue];
        }
    }
 }
```

`timerange.duration` is what you expect for.

And you have to draw buffer progress manually.

Refs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495433/uislider-with-progressview-combined).

Comment: thanks for your reply, just to be sure, the 'timerange.duration' is the duration already loaded? or already played? And what if I pause the audio? will the buffering continue and the 'timerange.duration' will progress?

Comment: Yes, `timerange.duration` shows you that AVPlayerItem loaded endpoint, otherwise `timerange.start` shows you startpoint. So, It's shows you loaded time not played time in CMTime type.

Comment: It works even your AVPlayerItem been paused, remote buffering and KVO will still work.