# Custom UIProgressView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

I am working on a custom `UIProgressView`. Please see attached image.

[image]

I am very close to it, but I am unable to add the circle at the begining of the pregressbar, like the current progress is 15% so the circle is placed on there.

Any Idea ?

Comment: How can this possibly be answered? Show a screenshot of the problem situation and show the code.

Comment: progressView.progress = 0.0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code like below...

```
[progressView setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progressView setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progressView setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//intial progress
progressview.progress=0.0;
```

Increase your progress

```
progressview.progress=progress here;
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you. `setMaximumTrackImage` and `setMinimumTrackImage` is the property of UISlider. I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495433/uislider-with-progressview-combined.